# I want to insert data into mysql database with express js but i am not able to insert it as well as get data into terminal

Tags: html, mysql, express

**HTML FILE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>CHAT APPLICATION</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Project/CSS/sty.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class=row>
      <div class='col-sm-12'>
        <h1>Welcome to chat application</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class=row>
      <div class=' col-sm-12 text-center'>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary button-press-1" data-target='#register' data-toggle='modal'>Register</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary button-press-2" data-target='#login' data-toggle='modal'>Login</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- connecting modal to the button for registration -->
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <!-- Modal -->

  <div class="modal fade" id="register">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Register</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form action="/" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Username">Username</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter your username" name="uname">

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Userid">Userid</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="enter your userid" name="uid">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleCheck1" name="passwd">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block register-1">Register</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>


  <!--connecting modal to button for login  -->
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="login">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Register</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form action="/" ,method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Userid">Userid</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="enter your userid">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Password">Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleCheck1">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg login">Login</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  </section>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="server.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**EXPRESS JS FILE**

```
var express = require("express");
var mysql = require('mysql');
var app = express()
var bodyParser = require("body-parser")
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false}));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/pro.html")
})



var conn = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'mydb'
});
conn.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("connected!!");
  }
  /*
  conn.query("CREATE TABLE mytable (Username VARCHAR(255), Userid VARCHAR(255), Password VARCHAR(255))", function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);

    } else {
      console.log("Tables created!!");
    }
    */
  app.post("/", function(req, res) {
    const username = req.body.uname;
    const userid = req.body.uid;
    const pswd = req.body.passwd;
    console.log(req.body);
    var sql = "INSERT INTO  mytable (Username,Userid,Password) VALUES (username,userid,pswd)";
    conn.query(sql, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log("Records inserted successfully!!");
      }
    });
  });

})
app.listen(3000)
```

I have tried all methods such as putting `method='post'` in HTML form. I have a database named mydb and I want to insert data in it.So I am using post request to get data from HTML forms.But it is not working.I want to console log the value of form that I have typed but I am not getting it in the terminal.

Comment: i have commented the section in which table is already created

Comment: Please tell me what error comes when insert query fired ?

Comment: erorr is not generated but i cannot get the value in terminal also it does not get inserted into the database @MaheshBhatnagar

Comment: Please tell me console.log(req.body);  is working ??

Comment: it is not working @MaheshBhatnagar

Comment: Means your control did not entry in route ??

Comment: yes @ Mahesh Bhatnagar

Comment: Can you share sample code ??

Comment: i have already given my code

Answer (score 0):

i hope this one help you :-

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO  mytable set Username='"+username+"',Userid='"+userid+"',Password='"+pswd+"'";
conn.query(sql, function(err, row) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("Records inserted successfully!!");
  }
});
```